# Remove main function from static library

Tags: c++, windows

Much of my code depends on a proprietary Windows library in .lib format (static library). Lets call it prop.lib.

The library works such that I make a new shared library that links to prop.lib.
I can then run my code through prop.exe (another program that loads my shared library and runs my code).

I want to create an executable that runs on it's own, but since prop.lib includes a main function, I get a linker error.

Is it somehow possible to remove the main function from the lib or create another entry point?

I use Visual Studio 2005.

**EDIT:** As of now I do not have the source code for prop.lib.

Comment: you should have two build targets: one for the executable and one for the library. the main should only be built into the executable, and not in the library.

Comment: @ChrisMaes       provided that the OP has an option to select the build target. If this is a part of data pack he received from his client/supplier, he need to go back to them and ask for a retargeted static lib

Comment: I'm using eclipse, so I'm just extrapolating :)

Comment: I don't have the source code for the static lib. I have updated the question.

Comment: @sighol          Where did you get it from? Can you not ask for a retargetted .lib ?

Comment: Rename the symbol with a hex editor? (no, don't really do this.)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin           Actually it's one of things that people used to do in Aeropspace to rehost OEM data into their own development systems - very difficult, but not unheard of

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult, necessarily - just search for main and change it to mzin or something.  Still seems like a pretty nasty way around the problem though.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin How do I do that? I have opened prog.lib in Sublime text. It is shown as hex. I converted ansi "main" to 6d 61 69 6e, but could not find it in the file. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should realize that this is rather low level task.

1. Work around: If you have acces to build configuration to your executable you can specify linker option /ENTRY in your executable build.
2. Microsoft's [editbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d25ddyfc.aspx) doesn't allow to perform such modification. So it seems that there is not exist official method to "hack" your *.obj files from Microsoft
3. Try to view in object files in your static library with [lib /list staticlib.lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xb6w1f8.aspx) If you're lucky and you have main.obj in separate object files,then just **/remove** that object file
4. If 3 doesn't help try It yourself to write application to edit symbols in COFF files.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx

From start of the object file pass +8bytes, read 4 bytes. It will be offset to table with "18 bytes structures with names. (if all names are then 8 bytes long)". Edit needed names with padding residual "name" bytes with zeros. I never try to work with COFF. I can't find anything like COFF editor in the web.